# How can I detach an entity from data graph using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have an entity `Vehicle` which references another entity `Type` through `TypeId`. I want to update `Vehicle` using Entity Framework but I don't want to update `TypeId` (or `Type`).

The problem is that Entity Framework wants to update the whole graph and the result is that the properties of the `Type` entity is overwritten with empty values when updating `Vehicle`.

I guess I could fetch the `Type` entity from the data source before updating, but it seems unnecessary to make two extra calls (read and save) to the database to update an entity not needed to be updated.

I would  much rather detach the `Vehicle` entity from the graph and only update only this entity. How can I do this?

Edit:

Here is some code to make the question clearer:

```
public async Task Update(Vehicle entity)
{
    var dataEntity = mapper.Map<VehicleDataEntity>(entity);
    await repository.Update(entity.Id, dataEntity);
}
```

As you can see the data entity is instantiated during mapping (using Automappar).

Updating is done in a simple generic repository:

```
public async Task Update(Guid id, TEntity entity)
{
    dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Here is the data model:

```
public class VihecleDataEntity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public VihecleTypeEntity Type { get; set; }
}

public class VihecleTypeEntity: IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste some code? Sounds like you have a bug related to incorrectly updating values. Detaching an entity is something you should almost *never* need to do.

Comment: @BradM Thanks for your reply. Added code as requested.

Comment: The code still doesn't make sense. Please post a full repo including your automapper maps. Also for example, `id` is an unused parameter. My initial guess is your automapper code has a bug. Better yet, just create a repo without automapper. You should never be mapping any model to a data entity either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only `VehicleDataEntity` properties, you can set `VehicleDataEntity.Type` property to `null`. That wouldn't delete the relation but, would prevent EF from updating properties of the related entity.